# Winapi GetOpenFileName Extension Filter not working

Tags: c++, function, winapi, std, getopenfilename

I'm trying to apply file's extension filters to the file's selection dialog.

This way works:

```
ofn.lpstrFilter =   
"(*.exe) Windows Executable\0*.exe\0"
"(*.ini) Windows Initialization file \0*.ini\0"
"(*.dll) Dynamic Link Library \0*.dll\0"
"(*.lib) Windows Library file \0*.lib\0"
"(*.conf) Windows Configuration file \0*.conf\0";
```

[image]

But when I'm assigning extension filters dynamically, via parameters, it fails, filters don't appear in the combo box:

```
LPCSTR filter = (LPCSTR)extFilter; //Contains string "bmp"

stringstream s;
s << "(*.exe) Windows Executable\0" << "*." << filter << "\0";
string ffilter = s.str();
ofn.lpstrFilter = ffilter.c_str();
```

[image]

I'm assuming the problem is in strings conversion, but can't figure it out.

Comment: Not tested, I guess the separator `'\0'` may do harm to `stringstream`. If so, how about using another character such as `$` as separator, and after finished building the filter, copy the string to an array of `char` and convert `$`s to `'\0'`?

Comment: Have you tried looking at `ffilter` in the debugger to see what it contains?

Comment: Any news here? People are waiting... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found an answer:

```
const char * extensionFilter = myParamVar; //Contains "JPG" string

string sFilter;
sFilter.append("Format: ");
sFilter.append(extensionFilter);
sFilter.push_back('\0');
sFilter.append("*.");
sFilter.append(extensionFilter);
sFilter.push_back('\0');

//Current filter content --> Format: JPG\0*.JPG\0

const char * filter = sFilter.c_str(); //Char string conversion
ofn.lpstrFilter = filter; //Set the filter to the sctructure's member.

//Opens the dialog and it successfully applies the filter.
if (GetOpenFileName(&ofn)==TRUE){
. . .
```

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
s << "(*.exe) Windows Executable\0" << "*." << filter << "\0";
```

Is passing null-terminated `char*` strings to `operator<<()`, and thus is effectively behaving the same as this code at runtime:

```
s << "(*.exe) Windows Executable" << "*." << filter << "";
```

The nulls never make it into `s`.

To insert the nulls correctly, you need to assign them to the `stringstream` as individual `char` values and not as `char*` values:

```
s << "(*.exe) Windows Executable" << '\0' << "*." << filter << '\0';
```

Also, the fact that you are type-casting `extFilter` is suspicious.  If you have to do that to get rid of a compiler error then `extFilter` is not a compatible data type to begin with, the type-cast is hiding a bug in your code.  Get rid of the type-cast:

```
LPCSTR filter = extFilter; //Contains string "bmp"
```

If the code fails to compile then you are doing something wrong and need to fix it properly.

On the other hand, if `extFilter` is a null-terminated `char` string to begin with, you don't need to assign it to a variable before passing it to `operator<<()`:

```
s << "(*.exe) Windows Executable" << '\0' << "*." << extFilter << '\0';
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a pointer to some temporary string that, according to http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/, "may be invalidated by further calls to other member functions that modify the object."

Comment: The "any further method calls" is unlikely, as there might not be any. More likely is that the temporary stringstream itself went out of scope and got freed.

Comment: There is no temporary involved.  The `stringstream` content is being assigned to a `string` variable that stays in scope until the dialog is dismissed.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - That's a good guess, but I don't see a call to a dialog in the posted fragment.

Comment: @VladFeinstein: We can clearly see an `OPENFILENAME` variable being used, and we know that has to remain in scope until the dialog closes. And we can see the filter being assigned to a local `string` variable and that variable then assigned to the `OFN` variable. So unless the `string` variable is inside of curly braces and the `OFN` variable is outside of those braces, the `string` data is in scope during the dialog call.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - if the problem was only with the 0-separators, as you suggest in your answer, the OP would likely get ONE incomplete filter, starting with `(*.exe) Windows Executable`, but NOT the garbage at the very first byte.

Answer (score 0):

A shorter version:

```
ofn.lpstrFilter = _T("Format: XML\0*.xml\0");
```